# Arrow appearing on nav-tabs Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nav-tabs. the problem is there is arrow appearing on the tabs when the tabs is active.
Here is the sample picture of the tab.
[image]
[image]

```
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li class="active"><a href="#tbb_a" data-toggle="tab" >Attendance</a></li>
       <li ><a href="#tbb_b" data-toggle="tab" >View Attendance</a></li>
     </ul><br>
```

I tried to remove the tab using display:none, and many more but failed.
I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find anything. Appreciate any kind of help. Ty.

Comment: Check css rules for any pseudo element which adds this icon

Comment: dude i've found it. It is from the sidebar. But how do i exclusively add it to the sidebar only and not disturb others?

Comment: Nvm, i'll figure it out myself. Ty